# Convert Japanese Time format (H29.12.1) to YYYY-MM-DD format in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, calendar

I'm processing a Japanese csv file using Python3+pandas.

The Japanese csv has a column representing time, the format is like H29.12.1.
I learnt that this format is a Japanese format, and **H29.12.1** can be converted to **2017-12-1** (in YYYY-MM-DD format).

My question is, Does Python or pandas provide a function to convert this Japanese time column to YYYY-MM-DD format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The current era is 平成 Heisei and began in 1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Japan)

With that information, we can read date, set the year to 1989 and add N-1, where N is the year number (right after `H`)

Here's an example function:

```
import datetime as dt
def parse_heisei(date_string, sep='.'):
    y, m, d = date_string.split(sep)
    return dt.date(year=1989 + int(y[1:]) - 1, month=int(m), day=int(d))
```

you can then [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) this function to your dataframe's date column.

example:

```
my_gregorian_dates = df.heisei_dates.apply(parse_hesei)
```

I'm sure you can also find a library that does this automatically, but I don't think the standard datetime module or pandas comes with this built in. Regardless, the function is pretty simple to write.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a pandas function to handle Japanese Imperial Calendar, you may need to write your own function to convert the dates.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def jp_date_to_yyyymmdd(dt):
    if re.match(r'\w\d+\.\d+.\d+', dt) is None:
        return None
    elif dt[0] == 'H':
        # HEISEI - 1989-01-08
        ymd = [int(x) for x in re.split(r'\.', dt[1:])]
        return pd.datetime(1988 + ymd[0], ymd[1], ymd[2])
    elif dt[1] == 'S':
        # SHOWA - 1926-12-25
        ymd = [int(x) for x in re.split(r'\.', dt[1:])]
        return pd.datetime(1925 + ymd[0], ymd[1], ymd[2])
    else:
        # You may add more conditions to handle older dates
        return None

df = pd.DataFrame({'jp_date': ['H29.12.1', 'H20.12.22', '']})
df.jp_date.apply(jp_date_to_yyyymmdd)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more specialized library to parse dates containing Japanese era names, I found [Japanera](https://pypi.org/project/Japanera/) to be helpful.

```
from japanera import Japanera
janera = Japanera()

# The library outputs dates corresponding to all eras starting with "H",
# as it's somewhat ambiguous which is being referred to
date_candidates = janera.strptime('H29.12.1', '%-a%-o.%m.%d')

# Use max(), with the assumption that the most recent era is the correct one
max(date_candidates)
# => datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 1, 0, 0)

# It can also parse the era names written in Japanese
# (no ambiguity here, so there is only one list item)
janera.strptime('平成29年12月1日', '%-E%-O年%m月%d日')
# => [datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 1, 0, 0)]
```